Wordpress Plugin Creation - Editing wp-includes/functions.php to debug, but not executing changes
First time working on Wordpress plugin (with latest Wordpress version 6.5.2, in a Docker container). I am getting this error when I activate / deactivate the plugin:
[07-May-2024 01:11:48 UTC] PHP Notice:  file_get_contents(): Read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6852

When I go to wp-includes/functions.php I find the error line 6852 to point to:
function get_file_data( $file, $default_headers, $context = '' ) {
    // THIS NEXT LINE IS 6852 IN FUNCTIONS.PHP - Pull only the first 8 KB of the file in.
    $file_data = file_get_contents( $file, false, null, 0, 8 * KB_IN_BYTES );

    if ( false === $file_data ) {
        $file_data = '';
    }

    // Make sure we catch CR-only line endings.
    $file_data = str_replace( "\r", "\n", $file_data );

    /**
     * Filters extra file headers by context.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$context`, refers to
     * the context where extra headers might be loaded.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param array $extra_context_headers Empty array by default.
     */
    $extra_headers = $context ? apply_filters( "extra_{$context}_headers", array() ) : array();
    if ( $extra_headers ) {
        $extra_headers = array_combine( $extra_headers, $extra_headers ); // Keys equal values.
        $all_headers   = array_merge( $extra_headers, (array) $default_headers );
    } else {
        $all_headers = $default_headers;
    }

    foreach ( $all_headers as $field => $regex ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/^(?:[ \t]*<\?php)?[ \t\/*#@]*' . preg_quote( $regex, '/' ) . ':(.*)$/mi', $file_data, $match ) && $match[1] ) {
            $all_headers[ $field ] = _cleanup_header_comment( $match[1] );
        } else {
            $all_headers[ $field ] = '';
        }
    }

    return $all_headers;
}

So I add this error log entry to see contents of $file:
function get_file_data( $file, $default_headers, $context = '' ) {
    // Pull only the first 8 KB of the file in.

    error_log($file);

    $file_data = file_get_contents( $file, false, null, 0, 8 * KB_IN_BYTES );

    ....
}

But the error persists pointing to line 6852 and no log appears in the error.log. Is Wordpress chaching functions.php? How do I clear it cache? If not, what have I missed? Thanks!
PS: My docker-compose is:
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypwd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wptest
      MYSQL_USER:  myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypwd
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"  # MySQL default port is 3306
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: myuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mypwd
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wptest
volumes:
  mysql: {}


Where stuff gets logged, might depend on your error_log setting. What do you get, when you simply put a var_dump($file); there?

Hi @CBroe, I added the var_dump($file) in place of the error_log and result is the same. Nothing logged at this step. It is a fresh install of the latest version, running on WSL2 + Docker/Win 11, so it has not been messed with prior. Thanks!

Any chance you are sym-linking your plugin and not directly installing it?

WordPress does not cache that file, but it is possible that you have PHP opcache tuned really high. Did you make any changes specific to that?

When logs aren't working, sometimes it is just easier to die($file); to get things to scream. Also, throwing a debug_print_backtrace() can help, too.

Hi @Chris Haas, thank you for your suggestions. The install is a clean, brand new install of Wordpress running in a Docker container leveraging WSL2 on Win 11. I have tried die but it is not hitting the functions.php. There has not been any PHP config done in WSL. I have added my Docker compose file to the question as FYI. Thank you!
